# How do I use the web audio api

Tags: firefox, web-audio-api

I'm following a tutorial but damn if I can't seem to get step one right.
My 32 bit windows 7 and 64 bit windows 10 machines are behaving the same way.

Notice the lack of speaker icon in the browser tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AudioContext in this demo is loaded like this:

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();
```

This is optimized for Safari webkit navigator and you will have an error
*ReferenceError: webkitAudioContext is not defined* in Firefox.

You can try this line instead:

```
var context = new AudioContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your AudioContext like this in order to handle all (most) browsers:

```
try {
  window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  context = new AudioContext();
}
catch(e) {
  alert('Web Audio API is not supported in this browser');
}
```